# IOS - Is it posible to calculate TextView height before it's drawn

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a custom `PopupView`(extends `UIView`). `PopupView` only contains `TextView`.
The width of `PopupView` is 220.
Now I want the `PopupView` height depend on `TextView` height like when `TextView` is short the popup will short.
Can I calculate `TextView` height before shown the `PopUp`?

Here is what I have done to make `PopupView` height depends on `TextView` height.
- I show the PoupView with the width and height = screen width and height
- After that I calculate `TextView` height after it drawn (in `layoutSubviews`)
- Then I update PopupView height
=> It will be better if I can get the `TextView` height before it's drawn

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
     [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
     CGSize sizeThatShouldFitTheContent = [self.contentTextView sizeThatFits:self.textView .frame.size]; // this return correct value of `TextView` height
     // After I get textview height, I update contraint height of PopupView
}
```

Comment: I think  to calculate  `TextView` height after drawn is the right way. Calculating it by the text is not accurate, since you have to think about the margin in `TextView`.

Comment: Why don't you use AutoLayout ?

Comment: @Lefteris , I'm using autolayout now. When show `PopupView` I add constraint width, height, center horizontal/vertical to window for `PopupView`

Comment: Don't set height constraint, and set it to be centered in superview

Comment: textview height set dynamic?

Comment: @Jayesh no, I don't change textview height

Comment: @Lefteris I remove the height constraint, the popup still show but the height of the TextView = 0, (no warning in log). Now In the xib file, I pin TextView (0,0,0,0) to supper view. What should I change in xib

Comment: Then its simple. You just get content size of textview and then set frame of textview.

Comment: @Jayesh but when I can get the content size of textview, before it draw or after it draw? my question is about how to get the textview height before it drawn

Comment: First you set data and then you manage the frame. You can't set size and then manage the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you asked for, but it is probably what you need: just remove the height constraint of the popup view, and disable scrolling for the text view (if scrolling is enabled, the default height is 0, otherwise the text view is resized automatically to fit the content). This way popup will wrap the text view.

You need to set constraints like so:

```
TextView.Top = Popup.Top
TextView.Left = Popup.Left
TextView.Right = Popup.Right
TextView.Bottom = Popup.Bottom
Popup.Width = <some fixed value> //Yay! Stairs :)
```

You can disable scrolling either programmatically: `textView.scrollingEnabled = NO;` or via the interface builder.